# CSS selectors/xpath and urls

Tags: html, dom, browser, xpath, css-selectors

I understand that if you insert an id to the end of a url i.e. foo.com#bar it'll navigate to the DOM element labeled with the id of "bar". Is this true of other css selectors or xpaths too?

How does the browser navigate to the desired ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser navigates to the first element that matches what's in the fragment identifier (i.e. the bit after the `#`, in this case `bar`). In HTML, an element is said to match if it's an `a` element with a matching `name`, or an element of any type with a matching ID. If there are duplicates, the browser should jump to the first among them, but given that you're not *supposed* to have duplicate names/IDs this behavior may vary from browser to browser and is therefore unreliable.

As for the jump itself, traditionally, this is not animated; the browser simply jumps to the top of the matched element. Whether the element is above or below the current scroll position does not matter.

The ID selector notation in CSS selectors actually takes after the hash fragment notation, not the other way around. Therefore, the notation only works with named anchors or IDs. It does not let you specify XPath or a CSS selector.

That said, there's a W3C Community Group exploring the idea of extending the notation to make use of selectors, aptly named [CSS Selectors as Fragment Identifiers](http://www.w3.org/community/cssselfrags), of which I happen to be a member. Of course, there are no implementations yet as it's just an idea for now.

Comment: Interesting. I'd not heard of the community group before. Seems unfortunate that the pattern uses "css()" given that the Selectors spec is steadily moving away from being CSS specific.

Comment: @Alohci: It's one of the newer but less active groups. And I agree; perhaps it could be renamed to `sel()` or something (and for that matter, the group renamed to Selectors as Fragment Identifiers). Nothing is set in stone at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It scrolls down (instantly) until the ID is placed at the top of the screen, and it only works for IDs.  You can not use other selectors (class, tag, etc).

Just like this URL: [CSS selectors/xpath and urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290202/css-selectors-xpath-and-urls/17290233#17290233)